# Which of the following formulas are valid?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I have to find which of the following formulas is valid , and if it is not valid, give a model to show it.

$\forall u(P(u)\rightarrow R(u))\rightarrow(\forall uP(u)\rightarrow \forall uR(u))$

$(\forall uP(u)\rightarrow \forall uR(u))\rightarrow\forall u(P(u)\rightarrow R(u))$

I don't know how to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

To show that:

> $(∀uP(u)→∀uR(u))→∀u(P(u)→R(u))$

is **not** *valid* we have to manufacture a counterexample.

Consider the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and interpret $P(x)$ as $(x=0)$ and $R(x)$ as $(x > 0)$.

We have that $\forall u \ (u=0)$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$; thus, the *conditional*: $∀u \ (u=0) → ∀u \ (u>0)$ is *true* in $\mathbb N$.

But: $(u=0) → (u>0)$ is *false* for $0$ as value for $u$; thus $\forall u \ ((u=0) → (u>0))$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$.

In conclusion, the formula: $(∀uP(u)→∀uR(u))→∀u(P(u)→R(u))$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$ and thus it is not *valid*.

Comment: Very Nice explaination !!!

Answer (score 1):

Well I'll address the other question then.

> $$\forall u(P(u)\rightarrow R(u))\rightarrow(\forall uP(u)\rightarrow \forall uR(u))$$

You are asked to show that, in every model over a universe $W$ with predicates $P ~:~  W \to \mathbb{Bool}$ and $R ~:~ W \to \mathbb {Bool}$ , that in all of those models the above equation is true.

Each of those predicates can be reprented by a sets:

- $P_s$ is a set defined by $x \in P_s$ iff $P(x)$
- $R_s$ is a set defined by $x \in R_s$ iff $R(x)$

Then

- $\forall u~P(u) \implies R(u)$ translates to $P_s \subseteq R_s$.
- $\forall u~P(u)$ translates to $P_s = W$
- $\forall u~R(u)$ translates to $R_s = W$

(Also, aside, primite logic equations tend be be written as $A \implies (B \implies (C \implies D))$ because it is equivalent to $(A \land B \land C) \implies D$).

So, you can establish the formula is valid if you can establish that from the assumptions:

- $P_s \subseteq W$
- $R_s \subseteq W$
- $P_s \subseteq R_s$
- $P_s = W$

the conclusion that

- $R_s = W$

You can use any proof technique to establish that proposition.  It doesn't have to be formal logic.  A Venn diagram of $P_s, R_s,$ and $W$ is fine.  Or just general set manipulation techniques is fine.  Keep in mind $A = B$ iff $(A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A)$.